# Is the factory pattern suitable for making more than one object?

Tags: design-patterns

I have to create a lot of objects which relate to each (i.e. one is passed in as a parameter of the constructor to the other) to do some work.

Usually factory type patterns seem suitable for making only one object. This is several. I was thinking of doing something like a fluent interface and then the properties on the class are the final objects, or use the specification design pattern. Is there any other better way?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some more info about your use case?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the [builder pattern](http://java.dzone.com/news/design-pattern-builder-pattern)

sorry, that link had a dead image, [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) may help also

Answer (score 1):

Consider using dependency injection.

You did not mention the platform, but if its dot net (as hinted by your username) then I suggest StructureMap.